# How to derive an interface from class properties (omitting methods) in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some class with all public members (essentially a struct) and I'd like to store its data:

```
class SomeClass {
  public foo: string;
  public bar: string;

  public getFooBar() { 
    return this.foo + this.bar;
  }
}
```

As part of the storage retrieval, I'd like to have an interface which properly defines it, eg:

```
interface ISomeClassData {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  // notice there is no getFooBar()
}

const test: ISomeClassData = magic();
if ("getFooBar" in test === false) {
  return "Success.  This is an interface, and not a class";
}
```

One typical (but inapplicable) way of doing such a thing would be like so:

```
interface ISomeClassData {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

class SomeClass extends ISomeClassData {
  // code omitted
}
```

In my scenario the amount of public properties in the class is very large, and it would be really, really easy for something to be added to the class without being added to the interface.  Instead what I would like to do is derive the interface from the class.

**Is it possible to derive an interface from class properties (omitting methods) in Typescript?**

---

Imaginary Example:

```
type ISomeClassData = JustThePublicProperties<SomeClass>
```

Comment: Look if composition over inheritance pattern fits your needs. It's using more interfaces, but in the end you and up with clean and extendable code.

Comment: I avoid inheritance as best I can, but I'm very literally shackled to a framework here.

Comment: Look at what "composition" pattern does. You don't inherit classes, but implement multiple interfaces, this way you group parameters into interfaces and then implement only the useful stuff for the current class. The interfaces are made to be implemented by classes, not the other way, so you might really be better off using composition and splitting all the stuff into the interfaces.

Comment: I'm very aware of what "composition" patter is and does.  It's my preference.  I literally showed an example of how that's what I would normally do in the question, then explained why in this case, it's not applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want all keys that are not functions, and you want to build an object out of just those keys.

```
// Get the keys that are not functions. We consider these data.
type ClassDataKeys<T> = {

  // Iterate over each property.
  [K in keyof T]:

    // If the property is a function...
    T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any

    // Functions are not allowed, use never to exclude it.
    ? never

    // Not a function, it is data, set the value of this property to its own key.
    : K

// Get the union of all values (which are now the keys that have not been set to `never`)
}[keyof T]

// Pick just the keys from the class that are ClassDataKeys.
type ClassData<T> = Pick<T, ClassDataKeys<T>>

// Works!
const test1: ClassData<SomeClass> = {
  foo: 'asd',
  bar: 'asd',
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=7&pln=14&pc=10#code/PTAEHEFMBdWgLSoDWkCeBnO8CGscBOSAdgPawBmArsQMbQCWpxGAdKAOpK3MYMAmkAtkgYk-PDlYBYAFDQ0AByQBhADY4MGACKSA0ugwAeACoA+UAF5QAbzlzQoEKACS0IXiSkAbkNCQcWnhQRQJSZQIFGVlHAG09UAZiFHRSClATAF0ALnsYxycwF3SEJFDwoQVErBxQajpGZlZmhwKTeMz-AA93Yn4sAApm1kIAcwxs0BxiNFjMgEorC2m0PILC0AAxGnomFimiUDJ8NTVSAHdIfgAaUCoxI8hfYWhSbto1KkFE6Gj1gH5Hs81gVnAA5chTOo7RrEW4MWAMLASaA4W5iWClUDeHCfLwleBIkJhCJVV4-LAXZKoNB-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)

Its a two step process. First is to use mapped type and a conditional to test to see if each property is a function. Then collect those property names that are not functions. Lastly, pick just the property names that are considered data from the class.