# Typescript extract public interface of a class

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Is there a mapped type that lets you extract the public properties and methods of a typescript class into an interface? It would look like this:

```
class Foo {
  private x: number;
  public y: number;
  
  bar(a: number) {}
  
  private baz() {}
}

type FooPublic = PublicInterface<Foo>;
```

In this example, `FooPublic` would have the property `y` and the method `bar()`, but would not have `private x` or `private baz()`.

The closest I have come is:

```
type PublicInterface<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]};
```

However, this doesn't appear to correctly type the methods. I get no error if I say:

```
const example: PublicInterface<Foo> = {
  y: 5,
  bar() {}  // Incorrect - should require an integer argument!
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken when you say that an implementation of `bar(a: number)` should require an argument. This is not true. the type `() => void` is a subtype of `(a: number) => void`

Comment: Ok. Good point, I was mistaken. Thank you.

Comment: Certainly, sir. In many languages that would be an error, but not in TypeScript as it statically models the semantics of JavaScript and, in this case, it is actually perfectly sound. If you wrote `bar(s: string) {}` you would receive an error.

Comment: A small addition `example.bar()` will require `a` argument  despite the fact that its implementation doesn't have it.

Comment: Here is the [link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcBOBLAbmAC4Cm0AHgFzQB2ArgLYBGJ2A3OlnUyLsNAE9q9Zqw4Zg8GhCLY6wIvGwAKKrUYtsAGkHCNrAJQpUASAxEAFrggA6ctAC8FU+au2BjwZwC+nTkzAVMD1RbCNkXwxOHAJiMgCAL2Vw319USWkiaAAzRE8aEgB3OERlAEYdACYDVFz4GwCVGtQiAUwyAAVuXmAASRpSbGywYBIAHgAVAD5PZABtAGloXBpoAGsSAXhs6AmAXWoJxb3vDnSpGWgScjAGTBASai6ePn7B4dGxhHgZpzQMITQACsWn8gWSKG8GAA9NDoP1JNhsCQFNAALTQCAWeB0EAAE2gyIAjnRcMjoGBVitSABzVgU7A0xgkAYAQlQvmut3uJAa4OarXaJXgzx6nlFrwGrA+42+UzYQA)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375506/how-to-derive-an-interface-from-class-properties-omitting-methods-in-typescrip) SO question shows how to extract only properties and omitting methods. It does not care about public/private qualifier though. It might be a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I think I've been through the same misconception as the O.P.

```
bar() {}  // Incorrect - should require an integer argument!
```

is correct. TS allows you to declare a function that takes less arguments than those "declared" in interface/type/... and still adhere to said interface/type/... The rationale is that you might not need those arguments in that specific implementation, so you just drop them.

But the required method signature is still at work, e.g. you cannot change the parameters type or order, nor you can add more of them:

```
// Type '(a: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(a: number) => void'.
bar(a: string) {}

// Type '(a: number, b: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(a: number) => void'.
bar(a: number, b: string) {}
```